# Voltage stabilization

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, motor, brownout

I have several motors, and a microcontroller.  The microcontroller sends 3.5v signals to the motors, which are powered by a separate 5v source.  (The microcontroller also runs off the 5v.)  Problem is, it seems like the power supply is insufficient.  When the motors start up, or when they're all trying to move, they often behave strangely, and the microcontroller sometimes resets.  If I increase the voltage, they behave better - but I have to increase it to like 6v, and I'm worried about pushing it much farther, since the microcontroller and motors are only supposed to get 5v.  Looks like the motors draw up to half an amp, collectively - which is a fair amount for small motors, but not THAT much.  With a multimeter, I've seen the voltage drop by over a volt.  I've tried two variable power supplies and a set of 4 AA batteries, and they each show significant voltage drop.  (One of the supplies was supposed to provide up to 3A.  Note that both supplies seem fairly inaccurate in the voltage they claim to be producing vs the voltage they're actually producing.)

How do I get the voltage to STAY at 5v?  (Or at least within 50mv of, say, 5.5v?)  Is there a particular style of power supply I need, or a special intermediate box, or do I just need a massive stack of batteries in parallel?  I wasn't measuring voltage AT the battery tips, merely at a convenient spot a little further downstream; only wires/connectors in the way - maybe the wires were adding some resistance??

Here's a video demonstrating the setup, and the problems.  [Demonstration video](https://youtu.be/1Ke6kLOmV2g)

Here's a diagram of the connections:
[image]

Comment: What are you using for a power supply? A good power supply will give its rated voltage up to its rated maximum current. A poor power supply will not.

Comment: You state in the second sentence that there is a separate 5V source but then you go on to say that it is the same source. Can you provide a picture or schematic of your setup?

Comment: @RonReiserer I mean that the microcontroller and the motors are powered by one 5v source, and the microcontroller only provides control signals (which are at 3.5v).  I can make a diagram, if you still want one.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy A Yihua PS-1501S, a QiYe-32430, and 4 Meijer Powercell AA alkaline batteries.  Link for the first: https://www.ebay.com/itm/15V1A-Precision-Variable-DC-Power-Supply-Clip-Cable-Digital-Adjustable-Lab-Grade/390681828322, link for the second: https://en.aliradar.com/item/4001199613667-adjustable-power-supply-ac-100v-240v-to-dc-3v-12v-3v-24v-9v-24v-1-24v-24v-36v-1a-2a-3a-5a-universal-adapter-for-cctv-led-strip

Comment: It would be useful to know what type of motor you are driving and how. Brushed DC motors are very noisy, and it could be the noise that's the problem, not the output of the power supply. Are you using a motor controller or are you trying to drive the motors with IO pins? A schematic with part numbers would answer many questions about the circuit that need to be understood before a valid answer may be given.

Comment: Start the motors soft or place a special capacitor for microcontroller - then you must increase input voltage to 5.4V and charged it via schottky.

Comment: If the motors decrease the voltage too low (and you don't want to add parallel bateries), then consider using boost converter for microcontroller or change  microcontroller to 3v3.

Comment: The problem may cause motors start current. Using soft start may improve. Looks like you controller works on 3.3V and it has internal stabilization. Dropping voltage to 4V not usually cause reset but short spikes which you can not measure by multimeter, may.

Comment: I've added a video and diagram to help.

Comment: I'd try without a breadboard and thicker wires. That might help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question you said the motor requires 5v thus you need a source that can provide 5v with a lot of current, I'd recommend you get a 6v SLA battery, it may be 6v but it's still safe to be used on 5v applications yet at the same time SLA batteries have a very low internal resistance thus there barely will be a voltage drop when you connect the motors and the SLA battery provides a lot of current. So try a 6v SLA battery, with a diode in series to keep it within the 5v requirement

Comment: The absolute maximum rating for a 5v0 microcontroller is typically either 5.5V or 6V; in both cases it's definitely exceeded by a 6 V SLA battery (a single cell of an SLA battery has a voltage of 2.1 V, making the total stack as high as 6.3 V)

Comment: But a series diode can fix that

Comment: Then you should update your answer to indicate that a series diode ought to be used.